# Can I receive messages in my iPhone as iMessage if it's turned off or out of battery?

Tags: messages

In case my iPhone is turned off/out of battery, will I be receiving messages as iMessage or text message?

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful:  from [PC Pro blog: How iMessage works](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2011/11/03/how-imessage-works/):

> If you send a message to a fellow iMessage user who has their data
>   switched off, the phone attempts to send it via the data channel at
>   first, but **if it can’t get through after five minutes or so, the
>   message turns green and is sent via the traditional SMS channel
>   instead.**  *[emphasis mine]*

See the article for more details.

This next might also be relevant if you have another iOS device you'd like to receive at instead, when your phone is off: [gigaom - iOS 5: iMessage](https://gigaom.com/2011/10/12/ios-5-imessage/):

> To ensure your Message is received on all your connected devices, you
>   must have them sent to your Apple ID email address. In limited
>   testing, if someone sent me a test message to just my phone number, I
>   only got the text on my iPhone. However, if they sent the message to
>   my me.com address (which is my Apple ID address), I got it on all
>   devices. This is because Apple can’t associate your phone number
>   (assigned by your carrier) with devices other than your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will receive them. They will wait in Apple's servers. Though, it won't say "Delivered" on the sender's phone I think...